# What is a simple way to uninstall Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I'm getting The Sims 4 on my computer, which takes up space. i've thought about it, and I think uninstalling Minecraft would free up space.

What is a simple and easy way to do this?

Comment: What OS are you on? Also note that Minecraft itself is tiny, it only takes up about 26MB of space (not including mods, texture packs, or saves). In comparison, The Sims 4 requires 10GB (10,000MB) of hard drive space.

Answer (score 3):

Truth be told, Minecraft is actually not that big of a game... It most likely won't free up your space that much. However in case it does for some reason, follow these steps

Start > Control Panel > Programs and Features > Look for Minecraft and click Uninstall (if you can't find it then right click on the Minecraft name in the list and you will see it).

If for any reason you can't follow these steps, you may want to bet your luck and open the directory where you installed Minecraft, it MAY (but don't get your hopes up) have an "uninstall.exe" file, which would remove the game from your system.

However the first and main solution is the best way to uninstall ANY game from your PC.

Edit: Solution posted in the comment, for your "mac"...

Comment: I have a mac....

Comment: You realize you downvoted me for giving you an answer without you even mentioning what OS you have... almost 80%+ of the world's users use Windows OS and you're expecting me to just somehow KNOW you have Mac... Not to mention how hard would it have been if you googled "how to uninstall an application on mac"... You just seriously made a programmer, martial artist and chess player sigh the biggest sigh he's made this day. **Also here's your "MAC" Solution** 
http://www.wikihow.com/Uninstall-Programs-on-Mac-Computers
I don't even need a thank you.

Comment: I ddn't downvote you...lol.

Comment: I upvoted you, don't worry. Anyway:
Your awnser is still valid for other users (after all, that's what Stack Exchange is for), just not MAC users.

Answer (score 1):

As you commented that you have a Mac, try:

Macintosh HD (Your Hard Drive) > Users > (Your Account) > Library > Application Support. Delete the folder "Minecraft" in there.
You can also delete Minecraft.app in Applications.